# What's with an j/w alternation in some PIE pronouns?

Tags: proto-indo-european, consonants, glides

There's a seeming alternation between *j (IEist notation *y) and *w in the PIE 2nd person pronoun (such as between *tewe and *toy) and in the reflexive pronoun (such as between *sewe and *soy). What's causing this?